# I want to print the complete elements name (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium

I want to print about 50 lines that I marked in the console.
not as .text
How can I print the complete line?
I wrote the .text code below. but I don't know the other.
I want to output like this
div id="cities_1_0" class="cities">17"
or just
id="cities_1_0"

Comment: I want to print about 50 lines that I marked in the console.
not as .text
How can I print the complete line?
I wrote the .text code below. but I don't know the other.

I want to output like this
<div id="cities_1_0" class="cities">17</div>
<div id="cities_2_0" class="cities">17</div>
<div id="cities_3_0" class="cities">17</div>

or just
id="cities_1_0"
id="cities_2_0"
id="cities_3_0"

Comment: all_spans = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cities' and text()='17'].id")
sayac = 0
for span in all_spans:
sayac += 1
print(str(sayac) + "--->" + span.text)
    
[enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRPi2.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to print the elements in the picture as they are